# Is there any performance issue in this code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

which way is better and why to get list item collections,

```
SPList list = web.getlist("listurl");
SPListItemCOllection items = list.getItems(query);
foreach(SPListItem item in items)
{
 ......
}
```

OR

```
foreach(SPListItem item in web.getlist("listurl").getItems(query))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this? You can use the `Stopwatch` class to find out.

Comment: @Steven nice idea, I can see difference, first one is     00:00:01.2412859  whereas second one is 00:00:01.234146  on a demo list

Comment: seems like 2nd one is fast as it takes less time

Comment: @user13814, do you have a bigger list to work with? the difference with these two is almost irrelevant

Comment: Can you flip the two code snippets around and measure them again? Is the second code snippet still faster? And is the performance difference relevant to your application. Make sure you're not doing any micro optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be the **same**, since `web.getlist("listurl").getItems(query)` will be evaluated before the `foreach` loop starts, so under the hood, both will do the same thing.